How to find similar if condition code with some pattern?
there's a case I have some buggy TypeScript code like:
if (whatever || xyz.startsWith("ABC")) {
 //
}

or
if (whatever || xyz.includes("ABC")) {
 //
}

can I find by pattern to list all matching code? Any VS Code extension to use? Maybe use some GPT(I use gemini though)?

Do you mean you want to find all occurrences of xyz.startsWith("ABC") expression (or with .includes) when used in an if condition? Possibly with any xyz and "ABC"?

You can use VSCode's built-in regex support in find and replace

@ghybs yes. and the expression xyz.startsWith("ABC") could be more general, the includes, indexOf are all possible occurrence.

I'm not too sure about your original intention. But this pattern should work for you
if (whatever || xyz.$METHOD("ABC")) {
   $$$BODY 
}

The $METHODand $$$BODY are meta variables that can match anything. $METHOD matches one single syntax node and $$$BODY can match multiple ones.
See also pattern syntax doc

https://ast-grep.github.io/playground.html#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

how to search "any expression that contains ABC or abc" if I use ast-grep, instead of xyz.$METHOD('ABC')?

@jiyinyiyong can you make an example on ast-grep playgrond?
